# Multipeer Connectivity MCSession Stop Advertising when connected results in disconnect

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, multipeer-connectivity, mcsession

I have a simple chat application which uses Multipeer connectivity to send text back and forth.

I am using the `MCSessionDelegate`.

```
-(void)advertiseSelf:(BOOL)shouldAdvertise{
if (shouldAdvertise) {
    _advertiser = [[MCAdvertiserAssistant alloc] initWithServiceType:@"messagingapp"
                                                       discoveryInfo:nil
                                                             session:_session];
    [_advertiser start];
}
else{
    [_advertiser stop];
    _advertiser = nil;
}
```

}

When the user connects, I call the below:

```
-(void)hideSelf{
    [self.swVisible setOn:NO];
    [_appDelegate.mcManager advertiseSelf:_swVisible.isOn];
}
```

I want the app to stop advertising as the application is a One to One communication app.

The problem is, this results in `MCSessionStateNotConnected`

I have set the `_browser.maximumNumberOfPeers` to `2` but I cannot see another way to hiding visibility whilst in session without causing the session connection to drop.

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should establish different sessions for each peer trying to connect to your host. By doing so, you would be able to deny the invitation without affecting other connected sessions.